# What would the equivalent \setlength commands be for letter and A4 paper?

Tags: margins, geometry

If one were type setting a business letter on A4 paper he might use:

```
\setlength{\textheight}{215mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-20pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{35pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
```

Is this correct for A4 size paper? And what would the measurements be for letter paper?

Comment: It depends on what you want or what are the preferences of the country you wrote the letter. With KOMA-Script class `scrlttr2` you get a very good typing area for example for german letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`layout`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layout) package to retrieve the lengths:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\layout

\end{document}
```

[image]

and

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}

\layout

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package, you can easily change these settings.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `geometry` package. Put it in his preamble.

```
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,inner=0pt,outer=0pt]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[letterpaper,twoside,inner=0pt,outer=0pt]{geometry}
```

Comment: Should it be 0pt?

Comment: @jhstuckey: I just copied his margins given in your question. It should not be zero in most cases.

Comment: that's the question: what the margins are for business letters.

Comment: @jhstuckey: It should be from `2cm` to `2.5cm` (in my personal preference).